# Verilog Example Wrong? Arbiter Code MSB Finder

Tags: verilog, hdl, digital-logic

In my book as an example it has:

```
wire [n-1:0] c = {1'b1,(~r[n-1:1] & c[n-1:1])};
```

If n=4 then c is 4 bits but the concatenation however makes 5 bits! 0.o 
)r is there something I don't understand about Verilog here, that maybe the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concatenation is infact just 4 bits. `r[n-1:1]` is an `n-1` bit value which in this case is 3. Note that `r[n-1:1]` means the bits starting from 2nd bit (index = 1) to nth bit ( index = n-1). So a 3 bit value concatenated with `1b'1` gives a 4 bit value.